# Invalid model name in action definition

Tags: python, xml, odoo-15

I am trying to create custom module in odoo 15.
when doing install it raise an error "Invalid model name 'school.course' in action definition"

My code as following:

**school/courses_action_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
      <record id="courses_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">course</field>
        <field name="res_model">school.course</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p class="o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
            Create a new course
          </p>
        </field>
      </record>
</odoo>
```

**school/models/Course.py**

```
from typing_extensions import Required
from odoo import fields, models

class shoolcourse(models.Model):
    _name = "school.course"
    _description = "Create a Course"

    title = fields.Char('Title',Required=True)
    description = fields.Char('Description')
```

**`school/models/__init__.py`**

empty

**`school/__init__.py`**

```
from . import models
```

**`__manifest__.py`**

```
{
    "name": "school",
    'depends': [
        ],
    'category': 'All',
    "sequence": 1,
    "data": [ 
              'views/courses_action_menu.xml',],
    "installable": True,
    "auto_install": False,
    "application": True,

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the course model to database, you can add the following line to the module `__init__.py` file or move `Course.py` to models and add the import there:

```
from . import Course
```

To make a field required, you just need to set the [required](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#fields) parameter to `True`.

> required (bool) – whether the value of the field is required (default: False)

Comment: I did named "__init__.py" with correct name but when I do a bold format in the post it omit the underscores . 
I did not do import for python file because by mistake I did not put the correct path in the post
for required parameter, you are right I did not put it as small letters but all that does not solve the problem I have

Comment: Ok, you just have to import the course file in module init file, which is missing

Comment: I already import the folder in my post that contains the Course.py file; which is " from . import models"

Comment: But the models init file still empty in your post, you need to import course file there

Comment: your are correct ; that is solve the problem, Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help and good luck